# Lang's definition of Operations on vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory, vector-bundles, functors

This is the vector bundle operations defined in Lang's Fundamental of Differential Geometry which I do not grasp the essence here.

Consider subcategories of banach spaces $\mathcal{A,B,C}$ and let $\lambda:\mathcal{A\times B}\to \mathcal{C}$ be a functor which is contravariant in the first and covariant in the second.

Let $f:E'\to E$ and $g:F\to F'$ be two continuous linear maps between topological vector spaces with $f\in Mor_\mathcal{A}(E',E),g\in Mor_{\mathcal{B}}(F,F')$, then by definition, we have $L(E,E')\times L(F,F')\to L(\lambda(E,F),\lambda (E',F'))$ assigning $(f,g)$ to $\lambda(f,g)$.

Q1: What is this definition talking about here? Can some one give me a concrete non-trivial example other than tangent bundle or cotangent bundle or symmetric forms or alternating forms(these are easy to understand) say both $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ position non-trivial?

Q2: What is the reason for this definition to be reasonable to first guess?

Comment: Some things are not clear with your question: 1. Subcategories of *Banach spaces*? How do you mean? From what follows, $\mathcal A,\mathcal B,\mathcal C$ rather seem some *categories*. 2. What's the difference between $L$ and $Mor$? 3. If $\lambda$ is contravariant in the first argument, the domain and codomain $(E,E')$ should be switched somewhere. 4. In this definition, exactly what are called '**operations**'? 5. And where are the vector bundles?

Comment: @Berci I am not exactly sure about the meaning of the statement either. I think you can interpret the category as complete topological vector space with a norm. So I would say he pulled back the euclidean metric of the bundle to define norm? $\mathcal{A,B,C}$ are some categories. $L(E,F')$ should be the morphism between $E$ and $E'$ in some category. I used two notations here. He called $\lambda$ the operation. I replaced $mathcal{A,B,C}$ by the category of vector bundles over some fixed manifold.